# Passing server error message to client (using Express and Backbone)

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, express, typescript

I've been thrashing for a bit and having difficulty figuring out how to pass server error messages to a client.

On the server I have (simplified):

```
export function get(req: express.ExpressServerRequest, res: express.ExpressServerResponse) {
    res.statusCode = 500;
    res.send('CUSTOM ERROR MESSAGE');
}
```

On the client:

```
public fetchObject(successF: Function, failF: Function): void {
    this.myObj = new MyObj();
    this.myObj.fetch({ success: successF, error: failF });
}


private failF(model, xhr, options): void {
   // Want to get access to "CUSTOM ERROR MESSAGE"
}
```

The xhr object responseText is empty and the statusText is always "error".

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution.  Define a class variable and capture the return from the fetch call:

```
private xhr: XMLHttpRequest = null;
```

Then:

```
public fetchObject(successF: Function, failF: Function): void {
    this.myObj = new MyObj();
    this.xhr = this.myObj.fetch({ success: successF, error: failF });
}
```

Finally:

```
private failF(model, xhr, options): void {
    doSomething(this.xhr.responseText);
}
```

this.xhr will contain the reponseText (i.e. 'CUSTOM ERROR MESSAGE').  The local xhr will still be a blank string.

I'm still not sure why this is the case, and if anyone has some insight I'd appreciate it.